PDO errorInfo() on ERRMODE_SILENT no longer reports errors after upgrading past PHP 8.1.7
We recently upgraded our PHP version to 8.3.10 from 8.1.0, and found that errors were no longer being reported when a query fails.
We use the PDO class to interact with out postgreSQL (version 13.15) database with ATTR_ERRMODE set to ERRMODE_SILENT, and use $statement->errorInfo() to identify if an error occurs and retrieve any relevant info. After upgrading, when a query fails we still receive a standard success errorInfo() success response (img below). The same issue occurs using errorCode().
Changing ATTR_ERRMODE to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION provides the error information, but would require vast changes across our codebase which we would prefer to avoid.
I tested a few different versions of PHP and found that this issue is introduced on PHP version 8.1.8. The changelog for this version mentions fixes for single-key connection strings, but that is all.
I've tried changing php versions, using errorCode(), using the errorInfo() function directly from PDO class instead of the the $statement var returned from the PDO::prepare() function. I've also tried passing the username & password into PDO declaration instead of a single string.
After some time looking online I haven't seen others reporting this issue.
Here's some example code:
// Example connection string;
$dsn = "pgsql:host=$conn; port=$port; dbname=$dbName; user=$user; password=$pass";

// PDO
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, null, null, null);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
 
// Prepare a PDO Statement
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE incorrect_col = 1;";
$statement1 = $pdo->prepare($sqlQuery);

// Execute the PDO statement
$statement1->execute();
        
// Fetch all results in an indexed array.
$results = $statement1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$error = $statement1->errorInfo();

The example code above produces the image below:

Is there a known solution to this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please take the tour
and read how to ask, an On Topic question,
then look at the Question Check list,
the perfect question and
how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

So basically if you show us the code, or some sample code that demonstrates this issue, it would be easier for us to be able to help you.

Thanks for the advice, I've updated the post with example code

Have you tested calling errorInfo directly after your execute statement? errorInfo provides "... error information associated with the last operation". So it may be lost when fetchAll is done.

Twas always so. And stated in the manual

Thank you ontrack for suggesting this solution.
As of PHP 8.1.8, you must call 'errorInfo()' immediately after triggering 'execute()' if you want to retrieve error information. Any subsequent PDO operation (like 'fetchAll()') will overwrite the last error stored.
Not exactly what I wanted to hear as we will still need to rewrite a lot of code, but at least there is an answer.
With errorInfo() called immediately after execute(), the error is returned:

